# X:Bind binding dropdownlist to bound list

Tags: uwp, binding, xbind

I'm stuck at figuring out how to bind a dropdown list to my bound listbox.
I would like to show a list containing all the passengers and their seatnumber shown in a dropdownlist. The admin should be able to change the passenger's seatnumber via the dropdown list.

I have tried looking into nested binding but I couldn't find anything that mentions my issue.

XAML

```
<Page
    x:Class="FlightApplication.Passengers"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:FlightApplication"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:fdata="using:FlightApplication.Models"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <ListBox x:Name="ListBox1" Margin="5" Width="450" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{x:Bind PassengersList}" FontFamily="Segoe UI">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Name="PassengerLineTemplate" x:DataType="fdata:Passenger">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="2">
                    <TextBlock>
                        <Run Text="{x:Bind LastName}"/>
                        <Run Text=" "/>
                        <Run Text="{x:Bind FirstName}"/>
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <Run Text="{x:Bind Class}"/>
                        <Run Text=" - "/>
                        <Run Text="{x:Bind SeatNr}"/>
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
</Page>
```

```cs
namespace FlightApplication
{
    public sealed partial class Passengers : Page
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Passenger> PassengersList = new ObservableCollection<Passenger>();
        public Passengers()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            //ListBox1.DataContext = PassengersList; Do i use this?


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, You mentioned the `Dropdown list`, you can try the `ComboBox` control. This is a control with a drop-down list. You can bind the `PassengersList` to `ComboBox.ItemsSource` and apply the current `ItemTemplate`.

Comment: @iCV: You could add a list of available seat numbers to your `Passenger` and bind to this one: `<ComboBox ItemsSource="{x:Bind SeatNumbers}" />`